# How to create a chart with dual y-axis using Google Visualization API?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

i am facing problem with drawing dual y-axis area chart.

i need to draw a chart similar to :[image]

here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/nehadhiman6/30bxL2me/2/

```
 function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Age', 'Weight','z-score'],
          [ 8,      12 , 12],
          [ 4,      5.5, 5],
          [ 11,     14, 9],
          [ 4,      5, 3],
          [ 3,      3.5, 8],
          [ 6.5,    7, 9]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
          hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},

          legend: 'none',

        };
```

Comment: So you want to plot Weight an the left axis and Z-Score on the right?

Comment: Exactly! @Aerials

Comment: Run the snippet in my answer to see the chart. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

### For a chart like the following:

[image]

You need to specify that you have more than one Vertical axis, then tell the chart builder which series belongs to which axis.

### See the example in action in the following snippet:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Age', 'Weight','z-score'],
    [ 8,      12 , 12],
    [ 4,      5.5, 5],
    [ 11,     14, 9],
    [ 4,      5, 3],
    [ 3,      3.5, 8],
    [ 6.5,    7, 9]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var options = {
    title:'Age vs. Weight and Z-Score',
    hAxis: {title:'Age', minValue:0, maxValue: 15},
    vAxes: { 
      0:{title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
      1:{title: 'Z-score', minValue: -20, maxValue: 20}
    },
    series: {
      0:{targetAxisIndex:0},
      1:{targetAxisIndex:1}
    },
    legend: 'top'
  }

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

**Useful documentation:**
[Charts docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#overview)